# Is there such a thing as a request-scoped singleton EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am writing a web application, where for each request, I would like to aggregate some information and pass it back to the user.

This aggregated information will be contributed by several different EJBs.

I would therefore like a sort of request-scoped singleton, so that all the EJBs could reference it easily (having a reference injected, rather than passed among them, but all referencing the same EJB)

As far as I can tell, @Singleton doesn't support @RequestScoped

So one solution would be to generate a unique id per request, and use that as a key in an application-wide singleton to differentiate user requests, but that seems horribly messy, especially if the same user might make multiple concurrent requests.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: why do you need such a thing? maybe you have a problem that could be solved in a different way

Comment: I have many different EJBs that will contribute to an aggregated response to the user. I don't want to have to pass a reference among them to a common aggregator. I would like to simply inject the common aggregator where it is needed. A singleton would work nicely , except that it is for all users for all requests. I would like the same thing as a singleton ie the same instance globally accessible but on a per-request basis. Grateful for any thoughts of how I could do this a different way. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Maybe aggregator should aggregate? Just create requestScoped java bean, inject in it all required EJB and build your response. I'd say that this object should be driving aggregation, rather than being passed around as a parameter. But maybe I misunderstood your need.

Comment: @Gas Thanks. Thing is that the controller references an EJB, which in turn creates other EJBs, which dynamically create other EJBs etc. I think I'm probably going to use the thread as the key to a hashmap in my aggregator. I'm not planning to do anything async. I don't see why the thread would change over the course of a request, and I don't see how more than one request can use it at the same time, so I think that should do the trick. Admittedly kludgy, but it's good enough for the production parameters I'm working with.

Comment: Update - using Long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId(); as a hashmap key in my aggregator seems to work very nicely to keep each request distinct. Have to clear the hashmap entry with that id out at the start and end of the user request, as the thread will most likely be re-used, being part of a pool.